# Horizontally center only the first and last card in a collection of inline-block cards with variable widths

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need only the first and last card in this set of cards to be horizontally centered. Each card's height is set to be 70%, so the width is responsive... if the width was a fixed percentage I could simply calculate what the margin-left should be to center the first card and calculate what the margin-right should be to center the last card, but the width is responsive and not fixed... any workaround for this?

Currently I've just made a guess and eyeballed what center would be by using margin-left and margin-right, but they are obviously not correct on all viewports. I need them perfect.

Maybe this requires JS? Really looking for a css solution though.

*TO CLARIFY* I am not looking to horizontally center all of the cards. I am only looking for the first and last card to be horizontally centered. The cards between the two are simply positioned inline relative to where the first card starts. A little tricky to explain, so here (https://jsfiddle.net/g5avo673/) is a JSFiddle demonstrating exactly what I mean. It is easily accomplished here because the widths are defined so I'm able to calculate what the margins need to be to center the first and last card, the issue with my code is that the widths are *not* defined, only the height, so I'm unable to calculate what the margins need to be when the widths are responsive.

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yn93phse/

Code:

```
<div id="horizontalproductcontainer">
  <div id="scrolling-wrapper">
    <div class="productcardfirst">
      <img src="images/.JPG" alt="." class="productimage1" />
    </div>
    <div class="productcard">
      <img src="images/.JPG" alt="." class="productimage1" />
    </div>
    <div class="productcard">
      <img src="images/.JPG" alt="." class="productimage1" />
    </div>
    <div class="productcard">
      <img src="images/.JPG" alt="." class="productimage1" />
    </div>
    <div class="productcardlast">
      <img src="images/.jpeg" alt="." class="productimage1" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    #horizontalproductcontainer {
      z-index: 0;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    #scrolling-wrapper {
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      -ms-overflow-style: none;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }

    .productcardfirst {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      height: 70%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      margin-left: 30%;
      padding-right: 3%;
    }

    .productcard {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      height: 70%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      padding-right: 3%;
    }

    .productcardlast {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      height: 70%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      margin-right: 30%;
    }

    .productcard img,
    .productcardfirst img,
    .productcardlast img {
      height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Could you add some sort of sketch of what it should look like?

Comment: I don't understand how the cards are meant to fall inline, but also be horizontally centered

Comment: @EliasFaraone - I have updated the question with a JSFiddle demonstrating exactly what I mean. My apologies for any confusion.

Comment: @JohnSmith No worries, I have posted a possible solution, see if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this and hope that it will work for anyone else running into a similar issue:

To reiterate, I had a string of images that needed to have a height of exactly 70vh. This resulted in variable widths, which made horizontally centering the first and last image within the string impossible without using javascript. The method that worked for my case was to wrap each image inside a div that had a fixed width percentage. For images that are super wide, this will not work, but in my case, the images are all exactly squares. Using this method, I can keep all my images' height at exactly 70vh, while still centering the first and last images in the string.

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8u4mbk17/

Code:

```
<div id="horizontalproductcontainer">
  <div id="scrolling-wrapper">
    <div class="productcardfirst">
      <img src="images/.JPG" alt="." class="productimage1" />
    </div>
    <div class="productcard">
      <img src="images/.JPG" alt="." class="productimage1" />
    </div>
    <div class="productcard">
      <img src="images/.JPG" alt="." class="productimage1" />
    </div>
    <div class="productcard">
      <img src="images/.JPG" alt="." class="productimage1" />
    </div>
    <div class="productcardlast">
      <img src="images/.jpeg" alt="." class="productimage1" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

#horizontalproductcontainer {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.productcardfirst {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  width: 40%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.productcard {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  width: 40%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.productcardlast {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  width: 40%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-right: 30%;
}

.productcard img,
.productcardfirst img,
.productcardlast img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your CSS by grouping common attributes as below and remove productFirst and productLast classes (you can keep them if you want to add extra styling), then make every product 100% width.
Given the above, all you need to do is to apply a left coordinate of 30% to all products (works for any number of elements):

```css
#horizontalproductcontainer {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: inherit;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.productcard {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  left: 30%;
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  /* padding: 3%; */
}


.productcard img {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontalproductcontainer">
      <div id="scrolling-wrapper">
        <div class="productcard">
          <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/QjuZKXnkLQgsYsL98uhL9X-650-80.jpg" alt="." class="productimage1" />
        </div>
        <div class="productcard">
          <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/QjuZKXnkLQgsYsL98uhL9X-650-80.jpg" alt="." class="productimage1" />
        </div>
        <div class="productcard">
          <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/QjuZKXnkLQgsYsL98uhL9X-650-80.jpg" alt="." class="productimage1" />
        </div>
        <div class="productcard">
          <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/QjuZKXnkLQgsYsL98uhL9X-650-80.jpg" alt="." class="productimage1" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, but unfortunately adding 50% to the left padding will not horizontally center the first card.

Comment: I am perplexed, you need the first product to be horizontally centered on the page, and running the snippet seems to do that (at least with the code you provided)

Comment: Here (https://ibb.co/BzGHLMG) is a screenshot of what the 50% padding is doing. It only places the *start* of the first product at the center of the screen. It does not center the card itself. The *center* of the product needs to be in the center of the screen, not the start of it.

Comment: Alright, got it. Unfortunately to do this you will have to use some javascript to query the DOM and get the first product width dynamically. I have updated the snippet above

Comment: Cool. The javascript appears to be working correctly, but the calculation appears to be slightly off as the *start* of the first product is still what is getting centered, not the *center* of the first product. The calculation to set the padding-left should be something like the following: (100% of the viewport width - the dynamic width of the first product) / 2. For example, if the width of the product was 30%, the padding-left should be 35% because 100% - 30% = 70% and 70% / 2 is 35%. Does this make sense?

Comment: Not really. In your example, the product would be 30% of its immediate parent (unless its position is absolute). But I do get what you are suggesting. I am starting to think your example code is not representative enough of the situation for us to help you out in any useful way

Comment: Yes, in the example, the product would be 30% width of a parent div that is set to 100% width. The example code shown here (https://jsfiddle.net/g5avo673/) is exactly the same as my code except that in my code, the size of the product cards are defined by a fixed height percentage instead of a fixed width percentage. If the javascript calculation were to first take 100% of the viewport and then subtract the width of the first product card in pixels and then take that and divide it by 2 and set that as the margin-left, it will center the first card. But I'm unsure how to properly calculate that

Comment: I was thrown off by the absence of an actual image in the tags, so I've added one and got it working while simplifying your css as well, let me know if the new answer works out for you :)

Comment: So, no javascript

Comment: I appreciate the simplified CSS, but unfortunately this still does not solve the problem as I am not able to add a fixed *width* to my images like you have in this solution. My images need a fixed *height* of 70% along with a responsive width.